# Read the HTML code of Websites

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to read the HTML code of websites, therefore I'm using this code:
One of my Fragments:

```
public class FragmentFavorites extends Fragment {
    View view;
    TextView text;
    Homescreen home = new Homescreen();
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorites,container, false);
        text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        try {
            text.setText(home.getHtml("http://pastebin.com/u7jHeNwf"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

here's the getHtml() I'm referring to:

```
public static String getHtml(String url) throws IOException {
        URLConnection connection = (new URL(url)).openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        connection.connect();

        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
            html.append(line);
        }
        in.close();

        return html.toString();
    }
```

Unfortunately my app stops running every time I scroll to this fragment/the getHTML is called. Anyone got an idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Odds are that you are facing network call on ui thread exception.

Comment: could u explain that a bit more, i'm a rookie at coding .-.

Comment: Coulnd't you use a library for the scraping ? Something like [this](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: You should connect to network in an AsyncTask, not on UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class FragmentFavorites extends Fragment {
        View view;
        TextView text;
        Homescreen home = new Homescreen();
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorites,container, false);
            text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            FetchHtml fetchHtml = new FetchHtml(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), FragmentFavorites.this);
            fetchHtml.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "http://pastebin.com/u7jHeNwf");
            return view;
        }

    public static class FetchHtml extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            Context mContext;
            WeakReference<FragmentFavorites> mClient;

            public RegisterGcmTask(Context context, FragmentFavorites client) {
                this.mContext = context;
                this.mClient = new WeakReference<>(client);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                  try {
                   return getHtml(params[0]);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String html) {
                super.onPostExecute(token);
                if (null != mClient && null != mClient.get()) {
                    if (null != html) {
                        mClient.get().text.setText(html);
                    } else {
                       mClient.get().text.setText("Error fetching html");
                    }
                }
            }

        private static String getHtml(String url) throws IOException {
            URLConnection connection = (new URL(url)).openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            connection.connect();

            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                html.append(line);
            }
            in.close();

            return html.toString();
        }

    }
}
```